# ui-router getting current path on state change for google analytics

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to get the path of the state to send to google analytics. There are some issues. I am using abstract states, so using something like toState.url wont work as it wont grab the entire url.

I thought of using $window.location.pathname on $stateChangeSuccess, but it turns out success fires before the url is updated in the browser. This means that pageviews get sent 1 page view too late. ie.

```
click about: sends nothing
click contact: sends about url
click services: sends contact url
```

Basically the end result should look something like this, but with the toState url or pathname:

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
  var path = ???; 
  ga('send', 'pageview', path);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks like you need to use $location instead to get the new path:

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
  $window.ga('send', 'pageview', $location.path());
});
```

Comment: This is not work for "Behavior" tab on google analytics site administration :( if you see this on real time it will work perfect! but just there not in "behavior" option